# Understanding psql prompts

Tags: postgresql, psql

What is the difference between `postgres=#` and `postgres-#`? I tried googling it and looking on the official site but could not get a hit for the symbols.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`psql` has *three* different prompts, [*source*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING):

> The prompts psql issues can be customized to your preference. The three variables `PROMPT1`, `PROMPT2`, and `PROMPT3` contain strings and special escape sequences that describe the appearance of the prompt.
>
> - **Prompt 1** is the normal prompt that is issued when psql requests a new command.
> - **Prompt 2** is issued when more input is expected during command entry, for example because the command was not terminated with a semicolon or a quote was not closed.
> - **Prompt 3** is issued when you are running an `SQL COPY FROM STDIN` command and you need to type in a row value on the terminal.

You can see the defaults with `\set` in PSQL, or [looking here in the source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/49ca462eb165dea297f1f110e8eac064308e9d51/src/bin/psql/settings.h#L26)

```
#define DEFAULT_PROMPT1 "%/%R%# "
#define DEFAULT_PROMPT2 "%/%R%# "
#define DEFAULT_PROMPT3 ">> "
```

These are all format strings. They render different in different prompt levels, from the source above describing `%R`,

> `%R`
>
> - In **prompt 1** normally `=`, but `@` if the session is in an inactive branch of a conditional block, or `^` if in single-line mode, or `!` if the session is disconnected from the database (which can happen if `\connect` fails).
> - In **prompt 2** `%R` is replaced by a character that depends on why psql expects more input: `-` if the command simply wasn't terminated yet, but `*` if there is an unfinished `/* ... */` comment, a single quote if there is an unfinished quoted string, a double quote if there is an unfinished quoted identifier, a dollar sign if there is an unfinished dollar-quoted string, or `(` if there is an unmatched left parenthesis.
> - In **prompt 3** `%R` doesn't produce anything.

So there ya have it, `%R` changes based on the PROMPT level.