# Trouble renaming a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, alter-database

Trying to rename a postgres database:

```
$ psql -d some_other_database
some_other_database=# ALTER DATABASE myapp_development RENAME TO myapp_development_old
some_other_database-# \l
                Name                |  Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |  Access privileges
------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------
 myapp_development                  | rails   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

No feedback whatsoever after `ALTER DATABASE...`!  I am logged in as a Superuser and not aware of any current connections (but not sure how to be certain of that). What am I missing?

**Edit:** I erroneously transcribed my prompt in my original question so 2nd line had `=#` when, indeed (thanks Daniel), it should have had `-#`. Fixed above, now.

Comment: what's missing: probably a semi-colon at the end of the ALTER command, assuming that you didn't copy verbatim the next prompt. This should be `-#` instead of  `=#`

Comment: I'm an idiot. thanks! missing semi-colon was the problem. Guess I just kept building my command. So, i'm guessing, the prompt `-#` vs `=#` provides a clue? Will pay attention to that moving forward…

Comment: I may delete this question because it's such a silly mistake… unless Daniel wants to post the answer and take credit for it…

Comment: This is explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-4) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING)

Comment: This one might also serve as master post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66413/understanding-postgres-prompts/66421#66421